# Is it posible to make a queue non durable in rabbitMq management portal

Tags: rabbitmq

Is it possible to make a queue non durable in rabbitMq management portal or via the command line tool ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If queue or exchange was once declared you can't change it parameters. Not via management plugin nor via CLI nor via API or else. If you want to have queue or exchange with the same name but different parameters, you have to delete existent one and then create new with desired parameters (don't forget to bind queue if you do that).

Note, that policies differs from parameters and they can be added, changed and deleted on existent queues and exchanges on-the-fly.

Also note, if you will delete and then create queue and/or exchanges, there are some chance to lost messages. For more details see [RabbitMQ change queue parameters on a production system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25274182/rabbitmq-change-queue-parameters-on-a-production-system/25282766#25282766) and [Toggle routing in Rabbit MQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26139187/toggle-routing-in-rabbit-mq/26143488#26143488) questions on SO.